# where does portage install packages to when I emerge?

Tags: linux, gentoo, portage

When portage installs a package after I `emerge some-package` where is it installed - my pwd or a specified directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it's specified in the ebuild file. Cool.

Comment: Not reliably, no.  If it's specified in the ebuild, it's likely either a very simple application, or what upstream provides is so messy each executable has to be specifically handled and placed carefully.

Answer (score 1):

`emerge -n portage-utils && qlist -e package`